# How can i customize react navigation v5 material bottom navigator?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, customization, react-navigation-v5

I was trying to customize my material bottom navigation tab but there is not enough resource on the internet as far as i searched. Can you help me with this problem?

Here is my current bottom navigation tab:

```js
import { createMaterialBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs';

interface IAppTabsProps extends IAppStackNavigationProps<'AppTabs'> {}

const Tabs = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator<AppTabsParamList>();

const AppTabs: React.FC<IAppTabsProps> = () => {
  return (
    <Tabs.Navigator labeled keyboardHidesNavigationBar initialRouteName="Home" shifting sceneAnimationEnabled>
      <Tabs.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={Home}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ focused, ...props }) => (
            <Ionicons name={focused ? 'home' : 'home-outline'} size={24} {...props} />
          ),
          tabBarBadge: true,
          tabBarLabel: 'Home',
        }}
      />
      <Tabs.Screen
        name="Profile"
        component={Profile}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: props => <Ionicons name="ios-person" size={24} {...props} />,
          tabBarLabel: 'Profile',
        }}
      />
      <Tabs.Screen
        name="Notifications"
        component={Notifications}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ focused, ...props }) => (
            <FontistoIcons name={focused ? 'bell-alt' : 'bell'} size={24} {...props} />
          ),
          tabBarLabel: 'Notifications',
          tabBarBadge: 4,
        }}
      />
      <Tabs.Screen
        name="Preferences"
        component={Preferences}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: props => <SimpleLineIcons name="settings" size={24} {...props} />,
          tabBarLabel: 'Preferences',
        }}
      />
    </Tabs.Navigator>
  );
};
```

Comment: What do you want to customise?

Comment: Render custom label, render custom tab item, etc.